# Subgroup in Free group of rank $2$ is isomorphic to a free group of rank $3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Consider the free group of rank $2$, denoted by $\mathbb{F}(x,y)$.

I want to show that the subgroup generated by $\{x^{2},xy,y^{2}\}$ is free group of rank $3$.

How should I approach this problem ? Any hints.

Comment: Look at "Groups, Graphs and Trees: An Introduction to the Geometry of Infinite Groups" by Meier.

Comment: Consider the free group of rank 3, denoted by $\mathbb{F}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$, and consider the map $\varphi:\mathbb{F}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\to \mathbb{F}(x,y)$ such that $\varphi(\alpha)=x^2,\varphi(\beta)=xy,\varphi(\gamma)=y^2$. Is it an isomorphism? Notice that showing that it is a surjective homomorphism is easy.

Comment: @Wore No, $\varphi$ is not surjective. The OP's question is precisely whether $\varphi$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with free groups, I like to think about finite graphs. In your situation, notice that you have the following covering of graphs (which is $\pi_1$-injective in particular):

[image]